# How do I define a generic variable in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

Consider two Typescript interfaces A and B:

```
interface A {
    propertyA: string;
    propertyB: string;
    propertyC: string;
    propertyD: string;
    propertyE: string;    
}

interface B {
    propertyF: string;
    propertyG: string;
    propertyH: string;
    propertyI: string;
    propertyJ: string;
    propertyK: string;    
}
```

I want to define a constant, a Key-Value Pair, that pairs a string value with either interface A or interface B.

```
const keyValuePair: { [key: string]: A | B} = {};
```

Then, a function would pass in a generic value, T, indicative of what the value in the Key-Value Pair would be, and I would return the Key-Value Pair with the appropriate value object:

```
export async function getKeyValuePair<T>(keyId: string): Promise<T> {
    if (keyValuePair<T>[keyId]) {
        return keyValuePair<T>[keyId];
    }
}
```

Obviously. The above will not work. But, how can I get it to work? If I was just doing interface A, I would do the following and it would work fine:

```
const keyValuePair: { [key: string]: A} = {};

export async function getKeyValuePair(keyId: string): Promise<A> {
    if (keyValuePair[keyId]) {
        return keyValuePair[keyId];
    }
}
```

I realize I could do the following:

```
const keyValuePair: { [key: string]: any} = {};
```

But I really want something better and would like to avoid use of "any" if possible. How would I do this?

Comment: What does "does not work" means? Can you reproduce an example in the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QBygHt9owBPVALmQGcwpQBzAbhz0JLPICEb7GIVu1ydSUCgGF+DZmzwFi4igBEZg4QrHcAourkKsAXyxZQkWIhQ9MIxVwnkAYvqHyOS7gHFXmjw4oACV93UU9HAEkQu21HAClorXCKAGkQwxNTBCIQemQAawhyADU4ABsAVwgABThgKBoMZABtQvJfAF0adAAfZB4jZABeTCM2IA) ?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, such as producing an unexpected result where the expected result and the actual result are spelled out.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mAVB4W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  Note that in the guidelines describing a [mre] it says that "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem.

Comment: Are you looking for [Generic Constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints)? Basically define `T` as being of a type that unions A and B?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior sure!

Comment: How does the compiler know that `getKVP("foobar")` should return a `Promise<A>` or a `Promise<B>`?  Isn't `Promise<A | B>` good enough like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG6zVm)?  And then you can check it yourself later?  Or are you saying "I need the developer to *assert* that `getKVP("foobar")` will return a `Promise<B>` because they know that the `foobar` prop is of type `B`." in which case, I don't know why you'd prefer `getKVP<B>("foobar")` to `getKVP("foobar") as Promise<B>` because at least the latter is explicit about the unsafe type assertion.  

Answer (score 0):

If you goal is to retrieve an object and cast it to a certain type you could do this:

```
export async function getKeyValuePair<T>(keyId: keyof T): Promise<T> {
    return keyValuePair[keyId] as unknown as T;
}
```

So you could use like this:

```
getKeyValuePair<B>('propertyF');
```